# EF6, EF5, SQLConnection. First load of data. Big time difference. How to improve speed of first load of EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-5, sqlconnection

I have recently made some performance tests of retrieving data from SQL  Server 2008 RT. I use Entity Framework 5, Entity Framework 6 and ADO.NET(SQLConnection class). When my application is invoked by me, the application loads data. So this is the first load of data in application. Later, the speed of EF 6 of CRUD operations is faster and is not hitting by waiting of execution.

I am amazed by the time difference between performance gains of SQLConnection class and Entity Framework 6:

1. The test was happened in a local network. Speed is 100Mbit/s.
2. Count ot items in the table "People" at SQL Server: 778 persons.
3. Time for SQLConnection:  00:00:00.1231548
4. Time for Entity Framework 6:   00:00:05.7594701 (FIVE seconds!)
5. Time for Entity Framework 5:   00:00:03.1855048(THREE seconds!)

**SQLConnection Code:**

*Time for SQLConnection:  00:00:00.1231548*

```
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            string connstr = "Data Source=FooSQLSERVER;initial catalog=FooCatalog;Persist Security Info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connstr;
            SqlCommand fooCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
            fooCommand.CommandText = "SELECT IDUser, Name, LOGIN, TELEPHONE FROM PEOPLE";
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader fooReader = fooCommand.ExecuteReader();                
            int id;
            string name, login, phone;
            while (fooReader.Read())
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(fooReader["IDUSER"]);
                name = Convert.ToString(fooReader["Name"]);
                login = Convert.ToString(fooReader["LOGIN"]);                    
                phone = Convert.ToString(fooReader["TELEPHONE"]);
                collEmpl.Add(new Employee() { ID = id, NAME = name, LOGIN = login, TELEPHONE = phone });
            } conn.Close();
            timer.Stop();
```

**EntityFramework 5 Code and EntityFramework 6 Code are the same(but the results are different):**

Time for Entity Framework 6:   05.7594701 (FIVE seconds!)

Time for Entity Framework 5:   00:00:03.1855048(THREE seconds!)

```
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        using (FooEntities context = new FooEntities())
        { 
            db.People.ToList();
            timer.Stop();
        }
```

**1. My question is how to achieve speed of loading data of Entity Framework 6 similar to SQLConnection?**

**2. Is this speed gain of SQLConnection over EF6 normal?**

**3. Why is Entity Framework 6 slower than Entity Framework 5?**

Comment: Presumably, your EF tests are including startup overheads that are not incurred when you're using SQL directly. Can you adjust your timing to just measure the query itself to get a more accurate comparison?

Comment: You will also want to fire up the SQL Server Profiler and trace exactly what SQL calls are begin sent to the server. That will enlighten you to what exactly EF is doing underneath the covers.

Comment: When you new up a new context, the model is loaded and this takes some time. Your speed comparison is not exactly fair.

Comment: @RorySolley, I've changed the code of measurig EF. However, it didn't change results.

Comment: You should measure a second identical call after the first one. By the way, you can use `StopWatch.StartNew()`.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, why should I measure identical call after the first one?) cause user will wait this 5 seconds at the first time.